# Laravel Logout a specific user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I know it is an old topic, and I know thousands similar questions exist(if not millions), but no one gives a specific answer to my question.
I have a ban feature in my system, where the master(or admin) of the app can ban unwanted users, but if the last have already open session, they still able to use the website without any problem(until they log out, then they can't log in again).
Currently, I moved to redis, and I arranged everything, but my problem still with users who are logged in before I implement a new solution, as in my system I have a kind of monitoring and I can see that they spend money and enjoy the website without any problem(ecommerce web app).
I won't add a check or middleware on every request, because that will just slow down the app.
Also, some solutions discussing about looking in session file from laravel, will not help in my case.
Any suggestion or solution?
**UPDATE**
I can access `redis-cli` and type `KEYS *`, and then I can see all sessions, but I don't know which one belongs to which user. How can I get a session in redis by user id and then delete it in Laravel?

Comment: I don't know how important it all is, but is just removing all the sessions a solution? Every user would have to log in again ofcourse, but it saves you soms couple of hours of programming.

Comment: you have to write a piece of code in the header that checks for a ban and logs them out. I've done this every time I've written anything (in fact it's essential), it goes in every call (even async json ones) it doesn't slow down the app, incidentally you also do this for password changes too. You can also write a websocket client receiver in javascript that broadcasts status changes so that their current session changes immediately in front of their eyes once banned

Comment: Can you post your code please? This makes it easier to help you. I believe you will have to create a "blocked" flag in the users table and thus check each request if the user is enabled to use the system.

Comment: I want to stay far away from any database changes

Comment: I already have a banned flag in the users table, but I don't like to make kind of middleware or check on each user's request

Comment: is there any unique item by that you can find that this user id needs to be logout?

Comment: `session()->forget('some_data');
session()->flush();` you need to add more data,this is too broad,what exactly is your code like?why `solutions discussing about looking in session file from laravel, will not help in my case`?

Comment: @DsRaj of course, I have the id of user, and is_banned column set to 1 already

Comment: @Moses if you don't want to add any condition then you can, remove those users from database like soft delete

Comment: i need to keep them, as the admin cann unbann them in anytime

Comment: but I have another question, is there any possibility to see all sessions in redis? that will help me alot. I tried $redis->get('users:'.$userId); but doesn't help, always i have an empty array.

Comment: yes, now I tried redis-cli, and then KEYS *, I can see the sessions, they are encrypted and I don't know which one belogs to which user

Comment: Are you able to login to your redis server?  Via SSH

Comment: yes I could do it, and I can see all sessions

Comment: Yes you are write that approach might not work as they are encrypted

Comment: excatly, i can't know which sessions belong to banned users

Comment: If you save your session in the table then, you get the solution but with the file/redis, I don't think so

Comment: Yes I agree too, I can confirm that with redis it is kind of impossible to know which session belongs to which user